# Unity change the text in 2 child objects in C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

This should be simple, but I can't work out how to do it. I have a prefab which is an empty gameobject with a sphere and two 3dtext objects in it. All I want to do is change the two text values. The first one is called "Port Name", the second is "Port Description".

With just one text object, this works.

```
foreach(Port p in GameData.gameData._ports) {
    GameObject port = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Port", typeof (GameObject))) as GameObject;
    port.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = p._portName;
    port.transform.position = p._portLocation;
}
```

However, I'm stuck when trying to get to both of them. This code is based on a suggestion from Unity pages (which errors on the find with "cannot not be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead")

```
foreach(Port p in GameData.gameData._ports) {
    GameObject port = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Port", typeof (GameObject))) as GameObject;
    TextMesh t = port.Find("Port Name").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    t.text = p._portName;

    t = port.Find("Port Description").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    t.text = p._portDescription;

    port.transform.position = p._portLocation;
}
```

I'm obviously missing something simple - but I can't see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var texts = this.GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh>();
texts[0].text = "first";
texts[1].text = "second";
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html

Comment: Components without an s. That was the mistake - thanks

Answer (score 0):

With just one text object, your code is good.
with two text object, you made a copy but use a conference.

Maybe it will work **like below:**

```
port.Find("Port Name").GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = p._portName;
port.Find("Port Description").GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = p._portDescription;
```